# Модификация фильтра WOOF в зависимости от текущей категории товара WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть такой [популярный плагин WOOF](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) для фильтрации товаров в WooCommerce. Он обеспечивает фильтрацию товаров по категориям, меткам и атрибутам. Но что делать, если у товаров в разных категориях атрибуты разные? Условно говоря, лапти надо сортировать по размеру, а самогон - по градусам. Понятно, что присутствие фильтра по градусам на странице категории товара "Лапти" будет только сбивать с толку.

Как добиться такого результата, чтобы фильтр WOOF на странице категории "Лапти" показывал только фильтр по размеру, а на странице категории "Самогон" - только фильтр по градусам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, плагин WOOF не содержит хуков и фильтров WordPress, которые можно было бы использовать для модификации перечня фильтров товаров, выводимого в сайдбаре. Анализ кода плагина показал, что html сайдбара формируется на основе большого массива параметров `$woof_settings`, а сам массив создаётся при чтении опции `woof_settings`.

В связи с этим было принято решение перехватить чтение опции `woof_settings` и отменить фильтры WOOF в зависимости от текущей категории WooCommerce. Рабочий пример кода в functions.php:

```
function ft_option_woof_settings( $value ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $category_filters = array(
        'opticheskoe-uplotnenie' => array(
            'pa_form-factor',
            'pa_transmit-rate',
            'pa_wdm',
            'pa_pon',
            'pa_operating-distance',
            'pa_wave-length',
            'pa_optical-budget',
        ),
        'mediakonvertery'        => array(
            'pa_media-transmit-rate',
            'pa_wdm-media',
            'pa_dip',
            'pa_lfp',
            'pa_design-type',
            'pa_transmitter',
        ),
    );

    $cats = explode( ',', $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] );
    foreach ( $category_filters as $cat => $filters ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $cat, $cats ) ) {
            foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
                unset( $value['tax'][ $filter ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $value;
}

add_filter( 'option_woof_settings', 'ft_option_woof_settings' );
```

Данный код объявляет фильтр WordPress, который срабатывает при чтении из базы данных опции `woof_settings`. Функция `ft_option_woof_settings` объявляет массив $category_filters, в котором категории (opticheskoe-uplotnenie, mediakonvertery) сопоставлены фильтрам WOOF по атрибутам (pa_form-factor и т.п.). Каждый фильтр в WOOF всегда имеет префикс pa_ (product attribute) и далее слаг атрибута, заданный в админке.

Строка `$cats = ...` получает в $cats текущий массив категорий WooCommerce. Дальше идет цикл по фильтрам категорий, и если категория в $category_filters отсутствует в текущем массиве категорий WooCommerce, то все связанные с ней фильтры атрибутов удаляются посредством вызова unset.

Очищенный массив параметров возвращается плагину WOOF, который выводит в сайдбаре только оставленные нами фильтры.

Так выглядят фильтры для одной категории:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так для другой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Если вставка и модификация кода вызывают некоторые проблемы, можно воспользоваться моим плагином [WOOF by Category](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woof-by-category/) в репозитории WordPress. Плагин создан на основе вышеприведённого кода.

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, а если в категории не должно быть фильтров, то нужно написать так? 'mediakonvertery'        => array(
            '',
        ),

Comment: Ну вроде да, `'mediakonvertery' => array()`. Да поставьте мой плагин из официального репозитория WordPress. Там настройки есть, и с ajax он теперь работает.